# how to give a Textured border in html on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to give a water  Textured top and bottom borders slide on hover.Don't know how to do this using bootstrap, CSS and html.can use over line and under line both.border should 3D embossed one.i want to apply this to a navigation bar.i want to float the border left to right and right to left.

i tried  :

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    padding: 20px;
}
#main {
    height: auto;
    width: 380px;
}
.pictureContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
.pictureContainer img:hover {

border-top:#333 solid 4px;
border-bottom:#333 solid 4px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You could use :before and :after with some background images, set the width, height, content: ""; Use absolute positioning.

Comment: You can try using the border image attribute http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVOOBz